# How to highlight in-text citations and endnote references after linking to them within a page

Tags: html, bibliography, citations

I link my citations to my endnotes and my endnotes to my bibliography in the following manner:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<hr />

<p>This is a citation where "[1]" links to "&uarr;" in Endnotes and vice-versa.<a id="citation1" href="#endnote1"><sup>[1]</sup></a></p>

<h1>Endnotes</h1>
<hr />

<ol>
 <li><a id="endnote1" href="#citation1">&uarr;</a>This is an endnote where this <a href="#Short title of reference"><i>Short title of reference</i></a> links to entire <i>reference</i> in Bibliography.</li>
</ol>

<h1>Bibliography</h1>
<hr />

<ul>
 <li><a id="Short title of reference">Here goes the entire <i>reference</i>.</a></li>
</ul>
```

Which yields:

## Title

---

This is a citation where "[1]" links to "↑" in Endnotes and vice-versa.<sup>[1]</sup>

## Endnotes

---

1. ↑This is an endnote where this *Short title of reference* links to entire *reference* in Bibliography.

## Bibliography

---

- Here goes the entire *reference*.

---

Now I want the item that [1], ↑ and the *Short title of reference* links to, to be highlighted when the corresponding link takes me to it. How can one achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how:

```
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <hr/>

  <p>This is a citation.<sup><a id="citation_1" href="#endnote_1" onfocus="highlight(this)" onblur="deHighlight(this)">[1]</a></sup></p>

  <h1>Endnotes</h1>
  <hr/>

  <ol>
    <li><a id="endnote_1" href="#citation_1" onfocus="highlight(endnote_1Content)" onblur="deHighlight(endnote_1Content)">&uarr;</a><span id="endnote_1Content">This is an endnote citing this <abbr title="Full book title"><a href="#bibliography_1">Short title</a></abbr> for a book.</span></li>
  </ol>

  <h1>Bibliography</h1>
  <hr />

  <ul>
    <li><a id="bibliography_1" href="#" onfocus="highlight(bibliography_1Content)" onblur="deHighlight(bibliography_1Content)"></a><span id="bibliography_1Content">This is a reference for the entire book.</span></li>
  </ul>

  <script>
    function highlight(x) {
      x.style.background = "lightgrey";
    }

    function deHighlight(x) {
      x.style.background = "";
    }
  </script>
```